# Should [extension] and [extensions] be merged on SO?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tag-synonyms

If you look at the questions asked in [extension](/questions/tagged/extension) and [extensions](/questions/tagged/extensions) you will see that both tags cover roughly the same area, though a very broad one - it's about extensions for all various things. Main difference is that [extension](/questions/tagged/extension) in addition contains questions about file extensions (*ouch*). While neither tag is particularly useful, people following extensions discussions might have an easier time if the two tags were synonymous. Could somebody with sufficient reputation propose merging them?

Comment: Which one is the master?

Comment: [tag:extension] is more common (and singular is consistent to the other tags I think) so it should be the master.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd almost prefer that they were both blacklisted, as there's almost always a better tag name to be used.  [file-extension](/questions/tagged/file-extension), [firefox-extension](/questions/tagged/firefox-extension), etc.

However, if it were to follow the same pattern as a similar tag, [plugins](/questions/tagged/plugins) (and its synonym [plugin](/questions/tagged/plugin)), then the plural would be the master tag.

Comment: That's something I might have suggested - but there are also cross-browser extensions, Android extensions, VC++ extensions and a bunch of other things that don't have a dedicated tag. Still, I try to merge [tag:firefox] and [tag:extension] into [tag:firefox-addon] whenever I see them.

Comment: [tag:plugins] would be useful when asking about a way to implement plugins in your own application.

Comment: @Joachim yeah I was just bringing up that tag to show what had been used in the past to determine which of the two would be the master tag